# Differentiability by tangent circles

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, general-topology, derivatives, differential-topology

I study differentiation, and trying to understand geometrical meaning of differentiability. My first guess was to use tangent lines, but geometrical meaning of tangent not obvious - it's usually said, that tangent - is local approximation of function, but this deffinition requires special definition of approximation, which differs from standart uniform approximation (like in Stone–Weierstrass theorem), so such defining of tangent realy looks like tautology (and metric used in this approximation actualy uses integration, which itself is oposite to differentiation).

My guess was, that tangent - is line, locally lying below or above of function, but it's totally wrong - i mean neither $\Rightarrow$ nor $\Leftarrow$ work with counterexamples given by $x^{3}$ and
$$\begin{cases} x\sin{\frac{1}{x}},\ x>0 \\
x,\ x\le 0
 \end{cases}$$
My last guesses - are about ["kissing" circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_circles). So question - is it true, that function is differentiable at point iff there are two circles, wich intersect function graph at point, with one of them lying below of the graph, and other lying above of the graph. Another guess is - function is differentiable at point iff there is circle, unique up to inclusion, intersecting graph and lying below or above of it. I have no ideas how to proove or contradict such statements.

Comment: There is no "standard" definition of approximation. In math, we approximate things *in the way we want* because it is useful in a *specific* context: linear approximation of differentiable functions is *local*. Stone-Weierstrass approximation is *global* in some *specific* norm (uniform norm). Fourier approximation is global in *another specific norm* ($L^2$ norm). The only thing relevant to the question "how should we approximate something" is "why do we want to approximate it in the first place".

Comment: A philosophical comment. A curve will have a "kissing circle" (traditionally called an *osculating circle*, which means the same thing) at a point only when it is twice differentiable at the point. The circle and the curve will have the same curvature at the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it true, that function is differentiable at point iff there are two circles, which intersect function graph at point, with one of them lying below of the graph, and other lying above of the graph?

> A function is differentiable at point iff there is circle, unique up to inclusion, intersecting graph and lying below or above of it.

No.
The map
$$
\begin{array}{r|rcl}
f\colon & \Bbb R & \longrightarrow & \Bbb R \\
& x & \longmapsto &
\begin{cases}
|x|^{\frac{3}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 0,\\
0 & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}
\end{array}
$$
is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=0$, but no circle passing through $(0,0)$ lies entirely (even locally around $0$) above or below the graph of $f$.

Intuitively, $|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}$ grows bigger than any circle around the origin.
Indeed, such a circle should have centre on the vertical line (if not, it would cross the graph of $f$ at the origin).
Say this centre is $(0,y_0)$.
The equation of this circle, near $x=0$, is $y = y_0(1-\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{y_0^2}})$.
It is easy to show that such a function cannot be always above or below $y = \pm |x|^{\frac{3}{2}}$ around $0$ (the sign depending on whether $y_0 >0$ or $y_0 <0$).

Same thing occurs with straight lines though.

Comment: This function is not differentiable at 0, set of partial limits of (f(x)-f(a))/(x-a) at 0 is [-1, 1], in yous example, so.

Comment: @nagvalhm Crap, you're right. Currently looking for another counter-example, but I think you that the result remains the same. Circle approximation is a second order approximation, so you'll just need to look for function that is not twice differentiable

Comment: @nagvalhm see the edit

Comment: Looks like i should start studing physics, didn't expect it would happen so fast...

Comment: @nagvalhm It's a good thing, in order to learn math, to question definitions. But it is wiser to question them in a pedagogical way ("why do we define that in this specific way?") than in a skeptical way ("I'm sure this definition is bad and I can do better"), especially when it comes to worldwide accepted definitions, settled a few centuries ago, and which have proven to be very useful (for instance, the notion of differentiability and linear approximation).

Comment: i will wisely skip yours impolite comment. How would you explain smoothness to a child then?

Comment: @nagvalhm Absolutely nothing in my comment is impolite, nor is intended to be. For your last question, there are tons of pedagogical resources on the internet (on this website for instance) that will answer this in a better way that I would.

Comment: i wouldn't ask if it would be there, i wouldn't, probably, formulate questions in that way, if, for example, continuity would be given as $f[CL(A)] ⊂ CL(f[A])$ by default, and sequences would be given as maps of cofinite spaces - all of this demand hard searching and not given by default, so please, let me ask questions in way i want to ask them, and yours choice - answer them or not.